# GOOGLE APP ENGINE - NDB - KEY

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have table A and AEXT.

I would like to use the same KEY/ID for AEXT as the relationship between table A and table AEXT are 1-1 and as the name suggests AEXT has extended/additional attributes of A.

Can someone please let me know how can I do this in NDB/Python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: IN addition to the answer you will struggle with appengine datastore until you drop the notion of tables. You have an entity store that you store/retrieve entities via a unique key. In addition you have set independent indexes defined for particular attribute combinations from the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two "tables" (really entity types) can have the same key name as long as they have different paths in the datastore. A path is the kind/name of the entity and all of its ancestors. So for example you could do:

```
a_key = ndb.Key(A, 'mykey')
aext_key = ndb.Key(AEXT, 'mykey')
```

Now these keys would be different, but you could construct them again using the same *key name*, `'mykey'`. And once you have the keys, you can grab the entities themselves.

Hope that helps!